# Usage: "told with personal archive"?

Tags: grammar

I started watching a documentary, which begins with the intertitles:

> This is a first-hand account of Harry and Meghan's story, told with never before seen personal archive.

OK, so --- "with personal archive"?  If it were "with personal footage," that would sound good, or "with footage from **a** personal archive."  But the former just grates.

It's like if I were to write, "I'm watching historical basketball archive from the sixties"* --- like, what?  Is this a British thing?

[I'm a native American English speaker.]

*As opposed to "I'm watching archival basketball footage...," which is the usage I would expect to find in, say, an American newspaper.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it looks like a peeve

Comment: *...with never before seen personal archive **footage / material.***

Comment: A poor editor, trying too hard 2 B brief.

Comment: The first sign of bad editing on parade here is the failure to hyphenate "never-before-seen" when it appears as a compound modifier before the noun it modifies. On the plus side, they did hyphenate "first-hand" in a similar syntactical position.